# Batch - Internet Verification

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a batch script for several hours, but I can't find the mistake!
I want to check, with the batch-script, if I have Internet Connection or not. I thought, that I can do that with ping. I am trying to ping my rooter. If I get an answer than I am connected with the internet and if I don't get an answer I don't.
The problem is, that the script always said, that I am not connected to the internet, but I am. I already wrote the script seven times, but I have always the same mistake.
I would be very thankful, if someone could tell me where my mistake is.
Thank you!!!

code:

```
@echo off
@title INTERNET

set ip=10.0.0.243

IF exist internet_TRUE.txt DEL internet_TRUE.txt
IF exist internet_FALSE.txt DEL internet_FALSE.txt

ping -n 1 %ip%

IF %errorlevel% == 1 GOTO TRUE
IF %errorlevel% == 0 GOTO FALSE

:TRUE
echo [*]Internet Connection: TRUE
echo [*]Internet Connection: TRUE >> internet_TRUE.txt

:FALSE
echo [*]Internet Connection: FALSE
echo [*]Internet Connection: FALSE >> internet_FALSE.txt

IF exist START internet_TRUE.txt
IF exist START internet_FALSE.txt

pause>nul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your program flow. After :TRUE you fall right through to :FALSE. Add a label :DONE after :FALSE and then put a GOTO DONE before :FALSE.

Simplified version:

```
@echo off
@title INTERNET

set ip=10.0.0.38

IF exist internet_TRUE.txt DEL internet_TRUE.txt
IF exist internet_FALSE.txt DEL internet_FALSE.txt

SET "Result=False"
ping -n 1 %ip% && SET "Result=True"

echo [*]Internet Connection: %Result%
echo [*]Internet Connection: %Result% >> internet_TRUE.txt

pause>nul
```

Comment: Now I have always TRUE as an answer

Comment: Swap your values to 0 GOTO FALSE and 1 GOTO TRUE. I will post a simpler version.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
@title INTERNET

set ip=10.0.0.138

IF exist internet_TRUE.txt DEL internet_TRUE.txt
IF exist internet_FALSE.txt DEL internet_FALSE.txt

ping -n %ip%

IF %errorlevel% == 1 GOTO TRUE
IF %errorlevel% == 0 GOTO FALSE

:TRUE
echo [*]Internet Connection: TRUE
echo [*]Internet Connection: TRUE >> internet_TRUE.txt
GOTO END

:FALSE
echo [*]Internet Connection: FALSE
echo [*]Internet Connection: FALSE >> internet_FALSE.txt
GOTO END

IF exist START internet_TRUE.txt
IF exist START internet_FALSE.txt

:END

pause>nul`enter code here`
```